# A way to change the colors of the NetLogo interface controls or the plot border?

Tags: user-interface, colors, netlogo

I'm trying to adjust the colors of the NetLogo interface for images which will go into a book. The light purple or aqua colors of the controls and the beige-ish border of the plot are not ideal, as they will be grey in black and white and make the text harder to read. I've checked the NetLogo documentation for some way to edit these, and I can't find anything about this.

Is there any way to change the color on these?

Comment: One possibility is to use netlogoweb.org to take your images.  You have more control there as you can tweak CSS styles.  I wouldn't call it "easy", but it's more possible there than in NetLogo desktop:  https://github.com/NetLogo/Galapagos/wiki/NetLogo-Web-Appearance-and-Styling  Of course, that won't help if your model doesn't run in NetLogo Web.

Comment: Another possibility is to use Photoshop or some such program.